# Why is the noteName value rendering multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to display the name of the note being played. If I console.log(noteName) inside the timeout, it will display each note name perfectly. However, if I try and use setState, then it will render way too many times. What am I missing?

The idea is that each note in the arpeggio is displayed as it's being played

```
const modes = {
    'ionian': [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12],
    'dorian': [0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12],
    'phrygian': [0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12],
    'lydian': [0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12],
    'mixolydian': [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12],
    'aeolian': [0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12],
    'locrian': [0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12],
  };

  const noteNames = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"];


const ArpeggioPlayer = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('ionian');
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [context, setContext] = useState(null);
  const [noteName, setNoteName] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    setContext(new AudioContext());
  }, []);

  const startContext = async () => {
    if (context.state === 'suspended') {
      await context.resume();
    }
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    if (!context || !isPlaying) return;

    startContext();

    const rootNote = 60; // middle C
    const scale = modes[mode];
    let arpeggio = scale.map(i => rootNote + i);

    arpeggio.forEach((note, i) => {
      let newNoteName = noteNames[note % 12];
      setTimeout(() => {
        setNoteName(newNoteName);
        const oscillator = context.createOscillator();
        oscillator.frequency.value = 440 * Math.pow(2, (note - 69) / 12);
        oscillator.connect(context.destination);
        oscillator.start();
        oscillator.stop(context.currentTime + 0.5);
      }, i * 500);
    });
  }, [context, isPlaying, mode, startContext]);
    
  return (
    <div>
      <select value={mode} onChange={e => setMode(e.target.value)}>
        {Object.keys(modes).map(m => (
          <option key={m} value={m}>{m}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <button onClick={() => setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)}>
        {isPlaying ? 'Stop' : 'Start'}
      </button>
     <h1>{noteName}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ArpeggioPlayer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you set the state (calling `setNoteName` for example), the component re-renders. On each re-render a new instance of `startContext` is created. Because the 2nd `useEffect` block is dependent on `startContext`, it triggers the `forEach` loop, which creates multiple timeout. However, the previous timeout are not clear, so the new and the previous timeouts are triggered, and they change the state, which causes more timeouts to be set, and so on.

You can either wrap `startContext` in `useCallback` or inline it inside the `useEffect` because it's not used anywhere else.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const modes = {
  'ionian': [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12],
  'dorian': [0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12],
  'phrygian': [0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12],
  'lydian': [0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12],
  'mixolydian': [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12],
  'aeolian': [0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12],
  'locrian': [0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12],
};

const noteNames = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"];


const ArpeggioPlayer = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('ionian');
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [context, setContext] = useState(null);
  const [noteName, setNoteName] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    setContext(new AudioContext());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!context || !isPlaying) return;

    if (context.state === 'suspended') {
      context.resume();
    }

    const rootNote = 60; // middle C
    const scale = modes[mode];
    let arpeggio = scale.map(i => rootNote + i);

    arpeggio.forEach((note, i) => {
      const newNoteName = noteNames[note % 12];
      setTimeout(() => {
        setNoteName(newNoteName);
        const oscillator = context.createOscillator();
        oscillator.frequency.value = 440 * Math.pow(2, (note - 69) / 12);
        oscillator.connect(context.destination);
        oscillator.start();
        oscillator.stop(context.currentTime + 0.5);
      }, i * 500);
    });
  }, [context, isPlaying, mode]);

  return (
    <div>
      <select value={mode} onChange={e => setMode(e.target.value)}>
        {Object.keys(modes).map(m => (
          <option key={m} value={m}>{m}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <button onClick={() => setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)}>
        {isPlaying ? 'Stop' : 'Start'}
      </button>
     <h1>{noteName}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<ArpeggioPlayer />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

The main problem with your code is that there's no way to stop or switch in the middle of playing. I would refactor your code by generating the audio context and playing in the same `useEffect` block. Whenever `isPlaying` or `mode` is changed, the previous `context` is closed, and a new one is generated, thus stopping the currently played context.

In addition, instead of timeouts, use the [`OscillatorNode` ended event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioScheduledSourceNode/ended_event) to play the next note if there's one.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

const modes = {
  'ionian': [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12],
  'dorian': [0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12],
  'phrygian': [0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12],
  'lydian': [0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12],
  'mixolydian': [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12],
  'aeolian': [0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12],
  'locrian': [0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12],
};

const noteNames = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"];

const rootNote = 60; // middle C

const ArpeggioPlayer = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('ionian');
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [noteName, setNoteName] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {    
    if (!isPlaying) return;

    const context = new AudioContext()
    
    const scale = modes[mode];
    
    let current = 0;
    let oscillator = null;
   
    const play = () => {     
      const note = rootNote + scale[current];
      const noteName = noteNames[note % 12];    

      setNoteName(noteName);

      oscillator = context.createOscillator();
      oscillator.frequency.value = 440 * Math.pow(2, (note - 69) / 12);
      oscillator.connect(context.destination);
      oscillator.start();
      oscillator.stop(context.currentTime + 0.5);
      
      current++;
      
      if(current < scale.length) oscillator.addEventListener('ended', play);
    };
    
    play();
    
    return () => {
      oscillator.removeEventListener('ended', play);
      oscillator = null;
      context.close();
    };
  }, [mode, isPlaying]);  

  return (
    <div>
      <select value={mode} onChange={e => setMode(e.target.value)}>
        {Object.keys(modes).map(m => (
          <option key={m} value={m}>{m}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <button onClick={() => setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)}>
        {isPlaying ? 'Stop' : 'Start'}
      </button>
     <h1>{noteName}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<ArpeggioPlayer />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```